# Does an XMLTextReader require special ACL permissions in IIS7.5?

Tags: iis-7.5

We are trying to port a web app from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5  and a main module just isn't working in 2008 R2: in IIS in Windows 2003 an XMLTextReader was able to read an xml file from a folder beneath the main web app folder:

```
       webapp
          scripts
          images
          styles
          xml
```

But in 2008R2  IIS7.5  the code isn't working.  Are there other permissions required on the xml folder besides read+execute for the XMLTextReader to use the physical path to the file?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions are based on the IUSR (anonymous by default) or the application pool identity.  The best tool to help determine if there are permission issues is using process monitor by sysinternals.  Auditing will tell you right away if there are denies.  If so, adjust folder security to meet your requirements.

http://www.iislogs.com/articles/processmonitorw3wp/